# Dev C keeps returning a wrong value

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
main() 
{
    int n; 
    printf("Introduce un número entero\n"); 

    scanf("%d", &n); 
    printf("Has introducido el número: %d", &n); 
}
```

Every time I run this C code I get 6487628 for n, I have uninstalled and installed it over and over again and it keeps doing that, I don´t know what else to do.

Comment: Typo: `printf("...: %d", &n);` should be: `printf("...: %d", n);`, `&n` is the memory address of the value.

Comment: *"I don´t know what else to do."* - perhaps compile with warnings enabled...

Comment: That's not the case: Your program returns the value you told it to.  That it doesn't return the value you expected _should_ tell you something about the error.

Comment: I'm surprise you get 6487628, _every time_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the &n in the printf(), you want n.  You are displaying the memory location n is stored in